# Using a Regular expression for password validation

Tags: java, xml, regex, validation, schema

I am using following regular expression my java code.

```
^.*(?=.{6,20})(?=.*[a-z].*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).*$
```

When I am trying to use same in xml as

```
^.\*(\?=.{6,20})(\?=.\*[a-z].\*[a-z])(\?=.\*[A-Z])(\?=.\*[0-9]).\*$
```

It is not working. It showing exception as below.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   cvc-pattern-valid: Value 'narendra1A'
>   is not facet-valid with respect to
>   pattern
>   '^.*(\?=.{6,20})(\?=.*[a-z].*[a-z])(\?=.*[A-Z])(\?=.*[0-9]).*$' for type
>   '#AnonType_passwordcreateUser'.

Can any one help in this regard.

Thanks,

Narendra

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but you should remove the first `.*` right after the `^`. It's unnecessary and makes your regex very inefficient. Also, if you think you're restricting the password length to 6-20 characters, you're not. A 100-character string will pass this regex just fine.

Comment: Why is there an upper limit of 20 characters?

Comment: @Gumbo: Doesn't matter, any string longer than 5 characters will pass, if you look at the regex closely :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does not directly answer your question, but it may be a better option for you than trying to do password quality checks with regexes.

The [vt-password](http://code.google.com/p/vt-middleware/wiki/vtpassword) library is an excellent Java library that implements rule-based password quality checking.  In addition to counting characters / character classes, it does things like checking against dictionaries, checking for passwords used previously, checking for repeated characters, etc.

(If you are using Spring, it is pretty simple to configure the password rule objects in a Spring XML wiring file.  This allows you to adjust the rules without changing your code.)

Answer (score 0):

Password Regular Expression Pattern

```
((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%]).{6,20})
```

Description

```
(           # Start of group
  (?=.*\d)      #   must contains one digit from 0-9
  (?=.*[a-z])   #   must contains one lowercase characters
  (?=.*[A-Z])   #   must contains one uppercase characters
  (?=.*[@#$%])  #   must contains one special symbols in the list "@#$%"
     .          #     match anything with previous condition checking
       {6,20}   #        length at least 6 characters and maximum of 20 
)           # End of group
```

Comment: Better use the complements instead of `.`. So `\D*\d`, `[^a-z]*[a-z]`, `[^A-Z]*[A-Z]`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern uses characters forbidden in XML document.
To make things simple put password into CDATA.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
^.\*(\?:.{6,20})(\?:.\*[a-z].\*[a-z])(\?:.\*[A-Z])(\?:.\*[0-9]).\*$
```